# Concatenate two 3D matrices in each page without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

Suppose two 3D matrices `a` and `b`, can these two be concatenated in each page/slice? For example:

```
a(:,:,1)=
1 2 3

a(:,:,2)=
7 8 9

b(:,:,1)=
4 5 6

b(:,:,2)=
10 11 12
```

So the output would be

```
output(:,:,1)=
1 2 3 4 5 6

output(:,:,2)=
7 8 9 10 11 12
```

As I understood, `cat` function will concatenate 3D matrix into 2D matrix, but I wanted to keep the 3D format. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
output = [a b]
```

Comment: dang! too much coding makes me blur! Thanks!